# PHP OOP: Handling multiple row outputs from a database, best way to do it?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to learn OOPHP and I think I'm getting there. I just don't know what the best way of outputting multiple database rows is.

The first method I've tried is doing the outputting normally within the function, but I think this kind of defeats the purpose of OOP.

I've also tried setting a `public $list` within the class that the database query pushes all the data to and then looping through the data outside the code, but ideally I'd like to create multiple instances of the object from the query and use their public variables (id, name, and eyecolour in my test case) to get the data so that the data always comes from the same place. But how do I create multiple objects from a query within the class and then how do I loop through them to display them, and how do I differentiate between them or just target a specific object with a specific value?

I have trawled through multiple topics but they all seem to focus on the problem in a specific situation. I'd like to learn it in this simple sense so I can then apply it to bigger projects.

Here is the code that I have been playing around with:

```
class Ignition {

public function dataConnection() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=oop_testing','root','root',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
    }

}


class People {

private $db;

// Each person has a
public $id;
public $name;
public $eyecolour;
public $list = array();

public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new Ignition();
    $this->db = $this->db->dataConnection();
}

public function getList() {
    echo "People:<br /><br />";
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM people");
    $sql->execute();
    //$this->list = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($person = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($this->list, $person);
    }


    /*while($person = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $person['name'] . "<br />";
    }*/
}

public function getIndividual($search, $by = "id") {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE $by = :search");
    //$sql->bindParam(":by", $by);
    $sql->bindParam(":search", $search);
    $sql->execute();
    $individual = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->id = $individual['id'];
    $this->name = $individual['name'];
    $this->eyecolour = $individual['eyecolour'];
}

}


$people = new People();
$people->getList();

/*echo "<pre>";
var_dump($people->list);
echo "</pre>";*/

foreach ($people->list as $person) {
    echo $person['name'];
}

$people->getIndividual(1);
echo "<br />Name: " . $people->name;
echo "<br />Eye Colour: " . $people->eyecolour;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option would actually to get a list of People objects how you do that is up to you. I would utilize PDO::FETCH_CLASS and use static functions something like this:

```
class People {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $eyecolour;

    public function display() {
        echo "Id: {$this->id} name: {$this->name} eyecolour: {$this->eyecolour} <br>";
    }

    public static function get() {
        $result = self::db()->prepare("select * from people limit 1");
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'People');
        $result->execute();
        return $result->fetch();
    }

    public static function getall() {
        $result = self::db()->prepare("select * from people");
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE,'People');
        $result->execute();
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }

    public static function db() {
        return new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb", 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    }
}


$person = People::get();
$person->display();
$all_people = People::getall();

foreach($all_people as $single_person) {
    //$single_person is an instance of People
    $single_person->display();
}
```

Obviously you can add search criteria to the `get()` and `getall()` methods like you have in your functions. I was just doing this as an example.

Comment: This seems to work for what I want it to do. So does `FETCH_CLASS` populate the properties based on the database column names?

Comment: Yes, if you want instead of this method you could get the results as a simple array and the create a function that sets the values of the object. Just all depends on the situation and what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

To practice OO, you may begin with setting all variables in the class to `private` (even when tempted to use `public`) and only use accessor functions. With this rule, because we are lazy, it is more likely that we put code in the correct place (inside the class).

Also, a good rule is that one object in real life should be one class.

In this specific case, I would create a class named `Person` with the different properties of a person (eyecolor, height etc.). The `People` class can create `Person` objects from what it retrieves from the database and store them in an array (maybe indexed by ID or name).

The `Person` class can take the whole row from the database as argument to it's constructor, and it then has to do the dirty work of setting/checking all variables itself. This is good for laziness and OO (no setter functions).

You may have an accessor function in `People` which returns a `Person` (searches for name, ID, etc.).

Comment: That makes sense, I will give that a go. How do I go about creating objects from inside another class? And how do I then access them in whatever script it is?

Comment: You define both classes `Person` and `People` objects in the same scope (file scope). Inside `People`, if you read from the DB row by row, you can do `$person = new Person($row);` (make the `__construct()` of `Person` able to take the whole row as argument and set its internal properties from that). You can then do `array_push($this->list, $person)` to save the person for later.

Comment: That was what I was trying to do originally, it just seemed a bit messy!

Comment: I guess it depends on wheter your goal is to practice OO or to just make the thing work. This other solution is best for the latter :)